# Replace multipal {blank} text to input box

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I try to replace {blank} text to input box but it replaces only one {blank} text to input box, I want to replace all {blank} text to input box. Below is the code for refrence

```
$(".editer-save .btn-primary").click(function(){
        $("#editor").each(function(){
            $this = $(this);
            $this.html($this.html().replace('{blank}','<input type="text">'));
            $('#editorPreview').show().html($('#editor').cleanHtml());
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use regex with `g` flag set for global match in string:

```
var r= '{blank}';
var re = new RegExp(r, 'g');
$this.html($this.html().replace(re, '<input type="text"/>'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use a regular expression instead of a plain string.

```
$this.html($this.html().replace(/{blank}/g,'<input type="text">'));
```

The reason this will work is that a plain string is only matched once, but a regular expression WITH a global flag (that's what the 'g' at the end is) will match all instances.